# What is the correct order for training the ML model?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, decision-tree, oversampling

I have a dataset containing multiclass dependent variable which is imbalanced. I want to know which is the correct order for training the model:

1)Standardizing-oversampling-traintestsplit

2)traintestsplit-Standardizing-oversampling

3)traintestsplit-oversampling-standardizing

Answer (score 0):

Welcome aboard.

About your question, the better approach may be:

```
preprocessing -> train test split -> normalizing -> over/undersampling
```

#### data cleaning and preprocessing

This must be your first task, this includes removing errors from data and joining all types of data needed scattered across the company.

#### train test split

This must be the next to do, because of 2 things:

- If you normalize the dataset before the split, you may contaminate your model training with test data information (models must be able to deal with unseen values)
- Test data must be real world data, as it is, if you apply any type of sampling on this, you are changing this reality.

#### Normalizing

Normalizing your data before sampling is a good practice, because some sampling methods use models to generate new data points, and receiving data normalized will make a better sampling generation.

#### Sampling

And at last, sample your data, i recommend you to evaluate different sampling methods and sampling ratios, and compare the results.